# java script refresh page after getting value from excel

Tags: javascript

i have this code in javascript

```
                a= Excel.Workbooks.open("C:/work/ind12.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells.find("value");
                if(a == null)
                document.getElementById('dateValid').innerText = "Date not Valid";
                Excel.close();
```

its just connecting with my excel sheet and finding some value,  it works perfectly fine But as as its done it refresh my page and all the values in text boxes and other just lost . is there any way to stop refreshing the page or retain my values

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason that this code would cause a postback. There must be a problem with some of the code you haven't posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like This:-

```
 var Excel;
        Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
        Excel.Visible = false;
        var a = Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/word/TEST.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value;
         if(!a)
        document.getElementById('dateValid').innerText= "Date not Valid";

        Excel.Quit();
```

Comment: also this Quit method is showing as "unresolved function" .. why is that , may be this is the reason .. thanks

Comment: i think you are doing some small mistake in your code ..otherwise page refresh does not happen .