# JavaScript: find index of some value in excel from javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I have this code in JavaScript

```
           a= Excel.Workbooks.open("C:/work/ind12.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells.find("value");
           alert(a);
           Excel.close();



             Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
       Excel.Visible = false;
       alert( Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/work/index.xls").ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Value);
       Excel.Quit();
```

This is giving me the value from the excel file , if it matched the value in excel it show the value else Null,  but i also want to get the index of that value , is there a way to get the index of that value.

Thanks

Comment: this doesn't look like javascript

Comment: Which library are you using to access Excel? Is it IE-specific, maybe? Also, puzzled that the random answer that somehow 'knew' what was going on, and 'fixed' it by tweaking the string paths, got deleted... meh. It's late afternoon, and I'm losing it.

Comment: i have edited my question above , there is the actual complete code to access excel file from javascript , but i didnt add any lib specifically for this .

Comment: Oh, this is Microsoft JScript stuff that's only available in IE

Comment: This is JScript, Microsoft's version of JavaScript. You can access Excel like this if you run the script using Windows Script Host, or if you crank down IE's security settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say index, do you mean the row the value is on?

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/work/ind12.xls");
var ws = wb.ActiveSheet;
var cell = ws.Cells.Find("value");
alert(cell.Row);
excel.Quit();
```

You can find more information on how to automate Excel from [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149067%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot , it works :)  , can you try answering my this quesiton as well     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075388/java-script-refresh-page-after-getting-value-from-excel